# createRadialGradient and transparency

Tags: transparency, gradient, html5-canvas, radial-gradients

I'm playing around with `createRadialGradient()` on HTML5 canvas. It works like a charm, except when I'm trying to implement (semi-)transparency.

I made this jsFiddle to make things hopefully clearer: http://jsfiddle.net/rfLf6/1/.

```
function circle(x, y, r, c) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    var rad = ctx.createRadialGradient(x, y, 1, x, y, r);
    rad.addColorStop(0, c);
    rad.addColorStop(1, 'transparent');
    ctx.fillStyle = rad;
    ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
    ctx.fill();
}

ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 256, 256);

circle(128, 128, 200, 'red');
circle(64, 64, 30,    'green');
```

What is happening is a circle (radial gradient) is painted at `(x, y)` with radius `r` and the color stops are `r` and `'transparent'`. However, the green circle is going from green to **black**, whilst it should go to transparent, i.e. the appropriate red colors of the background circle.

How does one implement transparent radial gradients on HTML5 canvas?

Comment: I'm not sure of the "proper method" of doing it, but this works: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/BD3xA/ - but there's surely a nicer way.

Comment: @thirtydot: Thanks - that works just fine. You ought to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, since you asked:

I don't know much about using `<canvas>` with JavaScript, but I do know about CSS3 gradients, and the usual way to work with transparency is to use `rgba` colours.

To make the gradient "fade out" to transparent, you can add a transparent version of the same colour.

That's what I did here: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/BD3xA/

Comment: Also great for linear gradients!